# Touchpad Smooth Scrolling Obliterated In Windows 10 Creators Update

Tags: drivers, touchpad, scrolling, microsoft-surface, windows-10-v1703

I love the Creators Update to an extent-- it has a good amount of features that are applicable for me on my Surface Pro 4. However, trackpad scrolling has just been completely obliterated. It's really been a nightmare. Here's all the problems I'm experiencing:

1. Scrolling in applications that support smooth scrolling have been slowed down to about half the speed, resulting in too slow of a speed. In order to offset this loss, I must set the number of lines scrolled to a higher number, but now applications that don't support smooth scrolling go way too fast!
2. Scrolling in applications that do not support smooth scrolling now jump x number of lines at a slower rate. Before the Creators Update, it would scroll one line at a time at a faster rate, resulting in relatively smooth scrolling. I often find myself disoriented when there's multiple lines scrolled at a time. Two examples I can give is Windows Explorer and Notepad++.
3. Applications that don't support horizontal scrolling don't scroll horizontally any longer with the touchpad(they did before the Creators Update).
4. I also had an issue where Eclipse would stutter immensely while trackpad scrolling([see here](https://gyazo.com/6bf33188277c1fc6fc92c58f7087050d)). I've since created a new copy of Eclipse and the issue seems to be resolved. Although, someone else has reported the same problem in IntelliJ. Not sure what's going on there. The three previous problems is really what I want focus on though. **Edit**: This specific issue fixed itself. Don't know if I did something or a Windows Update fixed the issue. **Edit 2**: The problem is back..

I've posted this in a few places, including Reddit(twice), Microsoft answers, the Windows Feedback Hub, and finally here. Someone told me on Reddit that previous to the Creators Update, trackpad scrolling directly manipulated scroll bars on legacy applications. He claims that mouse scroll events are now sent to the application. I want to know if this is true and if other people experience some of the same symptoms on their laptops. Ultimately, I'm asking if this is related to Windows or the Surface firmware/drivers. If Windows related, is there a possibility to revert to previous functionality? Something that can be tweaked in the registry perhaps?

Edit: My poll [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/67y7e9/poll_trackpad_scrolling_after_creators_update/) indicates there's something up with Windows 10 itself.

Comment: Have you verified you are using the current SP4 firmware?  Honestly this sounds like a firmware problem.  Have you contacted Microsoft Support about this and/or reported the problems with your SP4 to Microsoft?

Comment: I assure you that I'm using the latest firmware/drivers. I've posted these issues on the Surface subreddit, Windows 10 subreddit, Microsoft answers, Feedback Hub, and finally, here. I've only gotten responses [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/65allr/scrolling_not_working_smoothly_after_creators/), and the comment from DHowett shed some light on the subject at matter, unless he's wrong. Can you confirm that trackpad scrolling does or doesn't behave the way I'm experiencing on your system(s)?

Comment: @Oldmana were you ever able to find a solution? On my new Dell XPS 13, I was shocked at how bad the scrolling in Explorer lists was. I'm new to Win10 on laptops (been using it for years on desktop), and Explorer scrolling in my 4-year-old HP work laptop is perfectly smooth, so I thought it might be an issue with this machine. But from what you're saying, it might be inherent in the Creators Update.